# Advantage .NET Data Provider fails in an SSIS package?

Tags: advantage-database-server

I have installed the Advantage .NET Data Provider Release 9.0 for Windows 
64-bit on a Windows 2008 R2 64-bit server.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am using the Advantage Data Provider within a Microsoft SSIS package. When I try to transfer data I get 
the error "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'ace32.dll': 
The specified module could not be found."

Answer (score 4):

I am purely guessing at this point, but I think this should help.
Unfortunately with the 9.x version of the .Net provider only the 32-bit version of ACE was deployed.  In addition, no clients included the 64-bit version of ACE.

(side note, in 9.x the 64-bit version of ACE was still named ace32.dll, but in 10.x it was changed to ace64.dll and is deployed with all clients that support 64-bit)

Try downloading the 64-bit version of the Advantage Server (see link below to 9.0).  The install is just a self extracting zip, extract the contents (don't install) and grab the ACE32.dll and AXCWS32.dll (both are 64-bit dlls).  Replace the 32-bit versions of ACE32.dll on the system (most likely placing them in the System folder).
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=12&Product=25&Platform=9

Answer (score 1):

Edgar is correct, I had to copy the two files from the install and put them into C:\Windows\System32.